# Detect SQL min date string in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, sqldatetime

In an angularJS application I'm working on, we are using a SQL server to provide data. Nothing odd there. I am tasked with working on the date sanitation, so objects that are passed into our application that have the SQL min date value are undefined, and ones that do have a date are javascript Date objects.

I know that during upgrades, sometimes the string that is defined for min date can change. Right now, it is 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z.  I cannot just do a string comparison because it could change.

My problem is, how do i determine this min date in javascript?  new Date(varThatIsMinDate) is a valid date.  MomentJS thinks its valid too, and it is technically a valid date.  I'm less worried about validation and more worried about "is it min date"

How do you determine min date === true from a zulu pattern 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z or similar in javascript?

My code so far, cause I know you are gonna ask for it:

```
if (response.config.responseType === 'json')        {
      for (var property in response.data) {
        if (response.data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

          if (property.toUpperCase().indexOf('DATE') > -1 || property.toUpperCase().indexOf('TIME') > -1) {
            console.log(property.toUpperCase());
            // Attempt to use JS built in date and validate
            var tmpDate = new Date(response.data[property]);
            if ($moment(tmpDate).isValid()) {
              // Make it a valid date object if it has a valid date
              response.data[property] = tmpDate;
            } else {
              // Make it undefined
              response.data[property] = undefined;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Thing is, its always valid, so this code doesn't work.

EDIT: I could cheat and use tmpDate.getUTCFullYear() === 1 but i'd like to know how to do this the right way.

Comment: Can't your just do `response.data[property] === "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"`?

Comment: are you using .net web api to serve the data down?

Comment: If i used response.data[property] === "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z", then sql server upgrades can possibly change the format of that string.  Yes, .net web api is serving the data.